# Dealing with Missing Data in RDD using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I am having some issues cleaning up with my data, particularly with missing data.

After parsing my data file and doing preliminary data cleaning, a snapshot of the data is as follows:

```
r2.take(5)
Out[210]: 
[u'2016-10-26 13.43.06 C03 R27 80327 ONYX E 2605',
 u'2016-10-26 18.16.57 C04 R34 80544 GOLD E 7094',
 u'2016-10-26 18.24.15 C04 R33 80544 GOLD E 6875',
 u'2016-10-26 17.43.57 C03 R19 80908 ONYX E 5214',
 u'2016-10-26 17.07.55 C03 R27 80436 GOLD E 3436']
```

Based off Spark tutorials, I do the following next steps to [eventually] create a Spark Data frame (I omitted some steps):

```
# Create RDD
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

# Load text files
parts = r2.map(lambda l: l.split(" "))
apachelogs = parts.map(lambda p: Row(
  date=p[0],
  time=p[1],
  category_code=p[2],
  item_code=p[3],
  purchase_ref=p[4],
  selling_team=p[5],
  language=p[6],
  gross_sales=p[7]))
```

After a few more steps, I attempt to run simple commands like .groupBy().count().collect() and run into errors. When I went back into my data, I noticed I had missing data, particularly, when I run the following:

```
parts.filter(lambda x: len(x) != 8).take(12)

Out[236]: 
[[u'2016-10-26', u'10.25.26', u'C04', u'800779', u'BLUE', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'11.19.42', u'C03', u'803817', u'ONYX', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'11.22.12', u'C04', u'8132705', u'GOLD', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'11.22.22', u'C04', u'8154705', u'GOLD', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'12.34.22', u'C05', u'8125781', u'ONYX', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'12.40.05', u'C05', u'812381', u'ONYX', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'22.16.42', u'C03', u'832347', u'ONYX', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'18.07.36', u'C01', u'852300', u'GOLD', u'E'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'11.26.39', u'C02', u'845424', u'BLUE', u'F'],
 [u'2016-10-26',
  u'12.16.00',
  u'C05',
  u'R39',
  u'845436668',
  u'BLUE',
  u'6975'],
 [u'2016-10-26', u'11.26.58', u'C05', u'83344280', u'GOLD', u'F']]
```

As you can see we're missing observations for the following columns: item_code, language, and gross_sales.

What I'm trying to do is if else statements (or something similar) so I could fix these columns. I've done this code in a SQL environment but not sure how I would translate this to a PySpark environment.

For example, here is my code in SQL if we were working in a SQL environment:

```
select date, time, category_code, 
if(item_code like '8%','',item_code) as item_code,

/* Lets look at this code in the example below*/
if(item_code like '8%',item_code,if(purchase_ref not in ('GOLD','ONYX'),purchase_ref,'')) as purchase_ref,

if(purchase_ref in ('GOLD','ONYX'),purchase_ref,if(selling_team in ('GOLD','ONYX'),selling_team,'')) as selling_team,

if(selling_team in ('E','F'),selling_team,if(language in ('E','F'),language,'')) as language,

if(gross_sales is null,language,gross_sales) as gross_sales
```

Lets look at one example. `purchase_ref` always begins with a number "8". For the `purchase_ref` column, if the `item_code` contains the `purchase_ref` number due to the values being shifted over because of missing data, then its result should be that number. If it contains a `selling_team` value, leave it blank.

The SQL code worked when I was attempting to fix the rows that had missing data.

My question is: 
How would I approach cleaning my data from this issue?

Also, would it be more feasible if I did it in a Spark Data Frame instead (I can imagine how I would approach this using Pandas `np.where` but not sure how that translates here)?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To be more clear on my preliminary steps, they are the following:

Import text files from AWS. Here is what it looks like raw:

```
myApacheLogs.take(25)
Out[227]: 
[u'  2016-10-26  13.43.06  C03    R27       84327  ONYX  E     2605                                        ',
 u'',
 u'  2016-10-26  18.16.57  C04    R34       896544  GOLD  E     7094                                        ',
 u'',
 u'  2016-10-26  18.24.15  C04    R33       867544  GOLD  E     6875                                        ',
 u'',
 u'  2016-10-26  17.43.57  C03    R19       8776908  ONYX  E     5214                                        ',
 u'',
 u'  2016-10-26  17.07.55  C03    R27       8654436  GOLD  E     3436                                        ']
```

I did some cleaning with the following:

```
r1 = myApacheLogs.filter(lambda x: x is not u'').filter(lambda x: x is not u'')
r1.take(10)
Out[209]: 
[u'  2016-10-26  13.43.06  C03    R27       84327  ONYX  E     2605                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  18.16.57  C04    R34       84544  GOLD  E     7094                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  18.24.15  C04    R33       84544  GOLD  E     6875                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  17.43.57  C03    R19       895408  ONYX  E     5214                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  17.07.55  C03    R27       86436  GOLD  E     3436                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  13.01.30  C05    R43       248945  GOLD  E     6956                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  10.07.10  C03    R29       863356  GOLD  E     0861                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  11.31.19  C04    R32       865684  ONYX  E     2595                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  13.31.33  C01    RR1       865690  ONYX  F     7093                                        ',
 u'  2016-10-26  14.06.37  C03    R20       865243  GOLD  E     6959                                        ']

def myFunc(s):
  results = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", s) # Properly space columns
  results = results.lstrip() # Remove whitespace on the left
  results = results.rstrip() # Remove whitespace on the right
  return results
r2 = r1.map(myFunc)
```

Comment: It would seem like `l.split(" ")` is too simple to properly transform your data into a tabular format, which is necessary to turn it into a Dataframe. May I ask how you load your data into an RDD?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with my preliminary steps. I followed a guide to work with AWS S3 data sources [link](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/03%20Data%20Sources/2%20AWS%20S3%20-%20py.html)

Comment: Can you just translate the if statements you already have to Python and implement your row-packing code in a function instead of a lambda?  Then use map with the function you define.

Comment: Could it be that the columns are separated by tabs? In that case you might want to avoid the substitution of whitespace and use `l.split("\t")` instead of `l.split(" ")`. If all goes well, this should give you rows of constant length.

Comment: Could you just load the text file directly to a dataframe with `sqlContext.read.text('pathtotext')`